# Select box not working in Mozilla 16.0.1with jquery ui-sortable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

[image]I have a jquery ui-sortable ordered **list** which is draggable,it's working fine.But my problem is I have a select box inside the **list** and it not working ,I can't even select a value from it.The following is my code.Please suggest a solution as soon as possible.Thanks in advance.

```
<ul class="sortable">
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Item 2</li>  
 <li>Item 4</li> 
 <select>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>c</option>
      <option>d</option>
      <option>e</option>
 </select>      
 <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

You can copy the above html and try it here http://jsfiddle.net/VPNP4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Format The HTML in correct manner currently you have put the select box worngly in ul either put it outside the ul or put it in another li or in the same li

try following

```
<ul class="sortable">
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Item 2</li>  
 <li>Item 4
 <select>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>c</option>
      <option>d</option>
      <option>e</option>
 </select> 
</li>      
 <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul class="sortable">
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Item 2</li>  
 <li>Item 4</li>
 <li><select>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>c</option>
      <option>d</option>
      <option>e</option>
 </select> 
</li>      
 <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Use the following Script code

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable",

});
```

means remove the last line you have written 
[jsfiddle.net/sumit_2201/6Q7LG/](http://jsfiddle.net/sumit_2201/6Q7LG/)

Comment: Hi, i want a select option corresponding each li,  if you want test please use this url  http://jsfiddle.net/VPNP4/1/

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by having a select option for each li. Can you elaborate or update the jsfiddle to provide a bit more detail?

Comment: Hi, <li>Item 1 <select>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>c</option>
      <option>d</option>
      <option>e</option>
 </select>   </li><li>Item 2 <select>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>c</option>
      <option>d</option>
      <option>e</option>
 </select>   </li>